# How to get current Web object from collection

Tags: powershell, web, spwebcollection

In the code below, I want to pass current web object to function Remove-CT(), How I do that?

```
site | Get-SPWeb -Limit all | ForEach-Object {
     $currentWeb = $_.SPWeb // please correct this line if wrong
     $Pages_Library = $_.Lists[$lookForList]

     Remove-CT($Pages_Library, $currentWeb)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_` is your SPWeb object. Your script should look like this:

```
$site | Get-SPWeb -Limit all | ForEach-Object {
     $Pages_Library = $_.Lists[$lookForList]
     Remove-CT $Pages_Library $_
    }
```

Or an even shorter version:

`$site | Get-SPWeb -Limit all | % { Remove-CT $_.Lists[$lookForList] $_ }`